# How to print even/odd number using XSLT function (User Defined Function)

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xquery, xslt-2.0

Here i'm trying to create user defined function and identify the even/odd numbers please any one can help us.

**Note#** **we want create** **separate functions** **for** **even** and **odd** **numbers**

**XML INPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<num>1</num>
<num>2</num>
<num>3</num>
<num>4</num>
<num>5</num>
<num>6</num>
<num>7</num>
<num>8</num>
<num>9</num>
<num>10</num>
</root>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<even>
    <num>2</num>
    <num>4</num>
    <num>6</num>
    <num>8</num>
    <num>10</num>
</even>
<odd>
    <num>1</num>
    <num>3</num>
    <num>5</num>
    <num>7</num>
    <num>9</num>
</odd>
</root>
```

Comment: Please show your current effort.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. *"We have 1 to 10 numbers and we want indentify only even/odd no. and print them."* is NOT **XML INPUT**

Comment: @ michael.hor257k - Add the xml example for your reference

Comment: @Umaima If your question is not answered, add your current XSLT and the expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - Added the expected output, Here we want to create two separate functions for Odd & Even numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can idenfify even numbers by the expression:

```
not($number mod 2)
```

This returns `true()` if the number is even, `false()` otherwise.

---

Achieving the output you show is trivial using:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <even>
            <xsl:copy-of select="num[not(. mod 2)]"/>
        </even>
        <odd>
            <xsl:copy-of select="num[boolean(. mod 2)]"/>
        </odd>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but here i'm trying to create two individual fucntions for even and odd numbers.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know what that means.

Comment: Want to generate out thru user defined function for even and odd